# $A \in GL(n,\mathbb C)$ be such that $0 \notin \{x^*Ax:x^*x=1\}$ ; then is it true that $0\notin \{x^*A^{-1}x:x^*x=1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Let $A \in GL(n,\mathbb C)$ be such that $0 \notin \{x^*Ax:x^*x=1\}$ ; then is it true that

$0\notin \{x^*A^{-1}x:x^*x=1\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x^* A^{-1} x = 0$ with $x \neq 0$, then we can let $y = {1 \over \|A^{-1} x\|} A^{-1} x$, and then
$y^* A y = {1 \over \|A^{-1} x \|^2 } (A^{-1} x)^* x = {1 \over \|A^{-1} x \|^2 } \overline{x^* (A^{-1}x)} = 0$, and since
$y^*y = 1$, we have a contradiction.

Comment: Why does ${A^{ - 1}} = {({A^{ - 1}})^*}$?

Comment: @H.S: It doesn't necessarily, however I made another mistake. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Please fix it.                              .

Comment: @H.S: Are you joking?

Comment: It is not true, but I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks .                         ......     .